# Error while updating Link Resolving in Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have recently upgraded Tridion from 2009 to 2011 SP1 and working on the link resolving.
I have updated the code as below

```
       public Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.ComponentLink ComponentLink
       {
        get
        {
            if (this._componentLink == null)
            {
                this._componentLink = new Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.ComponentLink(261);
            }
            return this._componentLink;
        }
      }
```

but when I am browsing the website it gives me following error

Java.Lang.Throwable: com.tridion.linking.Linking.getLogger()Lcom/tridion/logging/Logger;

Detail Error

[Throwable: com.tridion.linking.Linking.getLogger()Lcom/tridion/logging/Logger;]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +373
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1365
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +524
   Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId) +127
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId) +28
   Project.Web.UI.TridionBasePage.get_ComponentLink() +88
   ASP.en_includes_controls_rss_items_ascx.get_componentLink() in d:\Websites\Project\en\Includes\controls\rss-items.ascx:7
   ASP.en_includes_controls_rss_items_ascx.Header_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Websites\Project\en\Includes\controls\rss-items.ascx:20
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +8996626
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

Comment: Check your Content Delivery log files for the real error...

Comment: Also, you may still have cd_link.jar in your lib folder, remove it. The new linking jar is called cd_linking.jar

Comment: Removed the cd_link.jar file and error is removed now. Thanks Nuno. If you will answer the question, I will accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the 64-bit version of Tridion 2011 CD ?
I think all previous .jar files(such as cd_link.jar etc) are not removed from the lib directory.
Could you please recheck it.

Answer (score 1):

When I have seen this error after an upgrade, it is usually because the now deprecated `cd_broker_conf.xml` is still in place. You can rename it to something like `deprecated_cd_broker_conf.xml`, restart your services and check again.

Other common causes for that kind of error is:

- You don't have the correct jars on your Web application [Check Here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_3E3A2FB1B4E34C20934B5A841C2E0930#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=linking&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1349868509324&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_DB20ECA59C824CC3BBB4644187D2C57A&query=&scope=&filename=ReferenceCDJARs.xml&docid=reference_DB20ECA59C824CC3BBB4644187D2C57A&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes, cd_broker_conf.xml was there. I rename the file but still the same error.